# How to contunally add to a number in SparkAR ( += equivalent)

Tags: reactive, spark-ar-studio

New to reactive programming and pretty lost.

I have a number (which can be positive or negative) coming into a script from a patch in SparkAR and I'd like to add the number to itself once every frame.

ie if the incoming number is 1 and it comes in 9 times the variable would be 9.

```
let intoScript = Patches.getScalarValue('intoScript').pinLastValue;

let myValue = Reactive.add(myValue, intoScript);
```

The above doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

One way-

Increment counter in Patch editor and send variable value to SparkAR.

(https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/docs/visual-programming/javascript-to-patch-bridging/)

Comment: If you want to achieve this only by script, please provide some more details as to when do you want to increment this value. First check if you're able to access the variable. Then check if you can subscribe to event which increments the variable. If both works separately, combine them

Answer (score 0):

```
let originalValue = Reactive.val(0)

function increment(newValue){

    Diagnostics.watch('originalValue', originalValue)
    originalValue = newValue.add(originalValue)
}
```

Don't forget to import Reactive module. more info about logical operations [here](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/reactivemodule)